# Bootstrap still shows navigation seperator for last hidden list item

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have noticed a slight issue with Bootstrap 3.3.7 navigation and the last hidden list item, it still displays a navigation separator.

It doesn't seem to matter whether the list item contains a dropdown class or not, the hide class seems to just prevent the list item from showing, the `ul#main-menu li:last-child` seems to be ignored.

Please see my sample code below:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" id="top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/" title="Home"><h1>WebApplication1</h1><span>@ViewBag.Title</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-right" id="main-menu">
                            @Html.MenuLink("Home", "Home", "Index", "Home")
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" title="Test" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Test <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    @Html.MenuLink("Link1", "Home", "LinkOne", "Link1")
                                    @Html.MenuLink("Link2", "Home", "LinkTwo", "Link2")
                                    @Html.MenuLink("Link3", "Home", "LinkThree", "Link3")
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown hide" id="notificationsLink">
                                <a href="#" title="Notifications" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span id="notificationsBadge" class="badge badge-primary"></span> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="notificationsList"></ul>
                            </li>
                            @*<li class="hide">
                                <a href="#">Test</a>
                            </li>*@
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

ul#main-menu li:last-child {
    border-right: none;       
}
```

Can somebody please help with this niggle?

Comment: can you please provide a working fiddle to understand your issue better.

Comment: Please see https://jsfiddle.net/xpnbjhvu/ I hope this demonstrates the issue.

Comment: If you require any further info, please don't hesitate to ask

Comment: The only way I have been able to address this issue is a very convoluted way round, which is to add the hidden list items via jQuery. When the page loads the hidden list items are not part of the DOM, jQuery code determines whether a link should be viewable and using jQuery append, I add the link to #main-menu. This prevents the right-outer navigation divider from appearing unnecessarily.